# Check if elements match an element from another array

Tags: perl

I have an array:

```
@Names = (A,B,C,D,E)
```

I want to setup a `next if` statement to skip if a string does not contain one of those elements. What is the best way to do that?

I figured something like this may work:

```
@someArray = (Foo, Bar, Yim, Print, Hello);

foreach my $string (@someArray) {
   next if ( $_ !~ $string ) @Names;
   print $string;
}
```

so only "Bar" and "Hello" should print out

I'm looking for the *best* way to do this and the *easiest* way to do this. But, I know they aren't always the same, so any input is great!

Answer (score 1):

One other approach might be to generate a single regular expression to do the job (if you actually need a case insensitive match, so that `Hello` matches, you should use the `i` modifier as well: `/$NamesRE/i`):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @Names     = qw(A B C D E);
my @someArray = qw(Foo Bar Yim Print Hello);

my $NamesRE = join '|', map {quotemeta} @Names;

for my $string (@someArray) {
    print "$string\n" if $string =~ /$NamesRE/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[first](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) will stop comparing as soon as it finds a match.  For `Bar`, once `A` matches, it does not check `B`-`E`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw(first);

my @Names     = qw(A B C D E);
my @someArray = qw(Foo Bar Yim Print Hello);

for my $string (@someArray) {
    print "$string\n" if first { $string =~ /$_/i } @Names;
}
```